# Integrity constraint violation for disabled input field in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have to keep a date `disabled` so that user can't edit it. But while I used `disabled` in `input` field, then a error is showing.

> **Integrity constraint violation**

I have tried with jQuery. But same problem. But while I remove disabled then there is no error. Information is saving to Database perfectly.

blade.php file:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="invoiceDate" id="invoiceDate" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}">
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a field that the user can't edit you should use `readonly` instead of `disabled`. Browsers will not submit disabled input.

```
<input type="date" ... readonly>
```